# Text Not Appearing In Container?

Tags: javascript, html, containers, chatbot

I'm writing some code for a Chatbot and everything is going fine except that the text that I write in my textbox is not appearing in my container. Here is all the code that is involved in the text appearing in the container:

```
<div id = "controls">
<textarea id = "textbox" placeholder = "Enter your message here..."></textarea>
<button id = "send">Send</button>
<br />
<input checked type="checkbox" id = "enter" /> 
<label>Send on enter</label>
</div>

$("#textbox").keypress(function(event){
if ( event.which == 13){
if ( $("#enter").prop("checked") ){

$("#send").click();
event.preventDefault();
}

$("#send").click(function(){

var username = "<span class =  'username' =>You: </span>";

var newMessage = $("#textbox").val();

$("#textbox").val("");

var prevState = $("#container").html();


if (prevState.length > 3){
prevState = prevState + "<br />";
}

$("#container").html(prevState + username + newMessage);


    }
    });
```

Does anyone know why this code isn't working?

Comment: Place your code inside the ready handler `$(function(){ });`

Answer (score 0):

Because the lack of indentation, it's hard to see, but your functions are a bit jumbled. For example, you only assign the `click` handler inside the `keypress` handler. I cleaned up the code like this:

```
$("#send").click(function (event) {
    send();
});

$("#textbox").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13 && $("#enter").prop("checked")) {
        send();
    }    
});

function send() {
    var username = "<span class =  'username' =>You: </span>";
    var newMessage = $("#textbox").val();   
    $("#textbox").val("");    
    var prevState = $("#container").html();
    if (prevState.length > 3) {
        prevState = prevState + "<br />";
    }
    $("#container").html(prevState + username + newMessage);
}
```

Here is a fiddle, so you can try it out: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H8cnt/1/)